# How to login to ASP.Net MVC website (Forms authentication) using HttpClient in Windows Store App?

Tags: forms-authentication, httpclient, windows-store-apps, antiforgerytoken

First I created the HttpClientHandler with cookie container

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
handler.UseCookies = true;
var hc = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Then I hit the Base Url just to get the cookie with "__RequestVerificationToken"

```
string r = await hc.GetStringAsync(BaseUrl);
```

Then I post the username/password to the login Url

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", "admin"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password),
});
HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.PostAsync(LoginUrl, content);
```

Then I get the server error "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present".

But when I check the request in fiddler, I can see that "__RequestVerificationToken" is already added in the cookies of the request.

Then I tried to login manually in IE, and check what kind of the request IE sent.

Then I discovered IE also put "__RequestVerificationToken" in the form, so I added the cookie in the form

```
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__RequestVerificationToken", cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(BaseUrl)).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "__RequestVerificationToken").Value)
```

Then I got this error

"Validation of the provided anti-forgery token failed. The cookie "_*RequestVerificationToken" and the form field "*_RequestVerificationToken" were swapped."

Then I couldn't get any search result on google for this error.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue.

The "__RequestVerificationToken" added to the cookie is different from the one added to the form.

So I took the value of "__RequestVerificationToken" in the form from the returned Html string, then it worked!

Comment: Thanks this also did the trick for me. Please mark this reply as answer.